# Objective C OpenCL Kernel Error Checking

Tags: objective-c, macos, opencl

My kernel seems to not work if I pass in a certain image2d_t but works if I pass in another, and I don't know how to check if there is an error.

My kernel code:

```
kernel void change_color(read_only image2d_t img, write_only image2d_t out) {
    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);

    int2 coords = {x, y};

    float4 v = {1, 1, 0, 1};

    write_imagef(out, coords, v);
}
```

Relevant host code:

```
cl_image_format format = {CL_BGRA, CL_UNSIGNED_INT8};
cl_image screen = gcl_create_image(
                                   &format,
                                   width,
                                   height,
                                   0,
                                   frameSurface);

cl_ndrange range = {
    2, {0,0,0}, {width,height,0}, {0,0,0}
};

change_color_kernel(&range, screen, output);
```

If I change

```
change_color_kernel(&range, screen, output)
```

to

```
change_color_kernel(&range, output, output)
```

the code works perfectly fine and the output image turns yellow; otherwise, the program runs as if the kernel was not invoked at all, and the output image remains unchanged.

Does this mean that passing `screen` results in some kind of error? How do I check what the error is, and what could be the cause?

Note: I do not know if my initialization of `screen` from `frameSurface` is correct.

Note #2: This is simply for testing purposes. I know that I'm not using `img` in the kernel, but the error should not be happening anyway.

Comment: If I use something besides `output` for the `img` parameter, it still works well. The problem only happens if I pass in `screen` (in which case, output is unaffected), but shouldn't my program crash or at least print something if there's an error?

Comment: passing {0,0,0} for the work group size is not the same as passing null, is it? You don't show where `output` is created. To check for errors, use the status code returned from each OpenCL API. If non-zero, it's an error.

Comment: What does the `change_color_kernel` function look like?

Comment: @Aderstedt It's automatically generated by Xcode. It's a little too long to post in a comment, but here's some of it:

   `gclCreateArgsAPPLE(k, &kargs);
    err |= gclSetKernelArgMemAPPLE(k, 0, img, &kargs);
    err |= gclSetKernelArgMemAPPLE(k, 1, out, &kargs);
    gcl_log_cl_fatal(err, "setting argument for change_color failed");
    err = gclExecKernelAPPLE(k, ndrange, &kargs);
    gcl_log_cl_fatal(err, "Executing change_color failed");`